# Get each attribute and its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, each

As an example lets say I have the following HTML setup.

```
<div class="element" data-xy-ko="value1" data-xy-ko2="value2">
   <span data-xy-ko="value3">testing</span>
   <ul>
     <li data-xy-ko="value4" data-xy-ko2="valu5">testing</li>
     <li data-xy-ko="value5">tsjbd</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

There are multiple data attributes. What some attributes have in common is that they begin with `data-xy-ko`, `data-xy-ko2` or any other combination as long as they begin with `data-xy-ko`

**QUESTION:** How can I get all the data attributes that match `data-xy-ko` and run an each loop for each attribute found where I can get each attributes value, element containing it, and do other stuff for each one found.

**EDIT** Multiple matching attributes my be found on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to select by attribute

```
$('[data-xy-ko]').each(function(i, e) {
    var attributeValue = e.dataset.xyKo;
    var elementContainingAttribute = e;
    // Do other stuff for each one found
});
```

Comment: If 2 or more matching attributes are found on the same element, it will only run the loop for one and not the other. So this method does not work

Comment: What would an element with two matching attributes look like?

Comment: Invalid HTML is what it would look like :)

Comment: By 'matching' I mean found attributes such as the two attributes in the first element I posted in the question. 'data-xy-ko' and 'data-xy-ko2' would be matching attributes as in they both start with 'data-xy-ko'

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer as I am changing the HTML from your premise, but this is a better way to handle what you are looking to accomplish, IMO.  I would do it like this:

```
<div class="element" data-xy-ko="value1 value2">
   <span data-xy-ko="value3">testing</span>
   <ul>
     <li data-xy-ko="value4 value5">testing</li>
     <li data-xy-ko="value5">tsjbd</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can say:

```
var myValues = $(element).attr('data-xy-ko');
var valuesArray = myValues.split(" ");
for(var i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {
    switch(valuesArray[i]) {
        case "value 1":
            // do stuff
            break;
        case "value 2":
            // do stuff
            break;
        case "value 3":
            // do stuff
            break;
        ...etc...
    }
}
```